# Path Integral involving complex plane.

Tags: complex-analysis

I need help evaluating the path integral $\int_{\gamma}|z|dz$ where $\gamma$ is the path from $-i$ to $i$ along

a) The imaginary axis

b) The right half of the unit circle.

c) The left half of the unit circle.

I believe this is an application of Cauchy-Goursat, but I cannot figure out the anti-derivative of |z|. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All can be solved by pre-university substitutions. The [Cauchy Integral Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem) Involves closed contours and homomorphic functions. None of your contours are closed. (You could use it to derive the answer to (C) from the answer to (B), but there's no need.)

**(A)**

If we are integrating along the imaginary axis from $-i$ to $i$ then $z(t) = (-i)(1-t)+it$ where $0 \le t \le 1$. Simplifying gives $z(t) = (2t-1)i$. If $z = (2t-1)i$ then $\operatorname{d}\!z = 2i\,\operatorname{d}\!t$. Notice that if $z=(2t-1)i$ then $|z| = |(2t-1)i| = |2t-1| \, |i| = |2t-1|$. Hence:

$$\int_{\gamma} |z| \, \operatorname{d}\!z = \int_0^1 |2t-1|(2i \, \operatorname{d}\!t) = 2i\left(\int_0^{1/2} (1-2t) \, dt + \int_{1/2}^1(2t - 1) \, dt\right)=\frac{1}{2}$$

**(B)**

If we integrate along the right half of the unit circle then $z(\theta) = \operatorname{e}^{i\theta}$ where $-\tfrac{\pi}{2} \le \theta \le \tfrac{\pi}{2}$. If $z = \operatorname{e}^{i\theta}$ then $\operatorname{d}\!z = i\operatorname{e}^{i\theta}\,\operatorname{d}\!\theta$. Moreover, clearly, $|z| = 1$. Hence:

$$\int_{\gamma} |z| \operatorname{d}\!z = \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} i\operatorname{e}^{i\theta}\,\operatorname{d}\!\theta = 2i$$

**(C)**

If we integrate along the left half of the unit circle then $z(\theta) = \operatorname{e}^{-i\theta}$ where $\tfrac{\pi}{2} \le \theta \le \tfrac{3\pi}{2}$. If $z = \operatorname{e}^{-i\theta}$ then $\operatorname{d}\!z = -i\operatorname{e}^{-i\theta}\,\operatorname{d}\!\theta$. Moreover, clearly, $|z| = 1$. Hence:

$$\int_{\gamma} |z| \operatorname{d}\!z = \int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2} -i\operatorname{e}^{-i\theta}\,\operatorname{d}\!\theta = 2i$$